# ConnectionString embedded localdb visual studio 2015 relative data directory

Tags: sql-server, database, vba, visual-studio, database-connection

I have a problem with the ConnectionString with visual studio.
when I use this :

ConnectionString 1 :

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\example\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Rexnord materials summury\Rexnord materials summury\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

the application works well, but since I need a relative data directory, I used this one.

ConnectionString 2 :

```
Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB ; Initial Catalog = Database1;Integrated Security=True
```

but i dosn't work, I got this error message :

[image]

can you help me with this? and how can I set a relative data directory with AttachDbFilename.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the relative path to the file, instead of Initial catalog?

```
 AttachDbFilename=".\Database1.mdf";
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer jessehouwing;  the relative data directory seems to be solved but I still cannot connect to the database

Comment: Generally the location of the executable.

Comment: I change the connection string like this but whitout any success.
con.ConnectionString = " Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=".\ Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=true;"
I have the same error

Comment: Is that a space you have between `.\ ` and `Database1`, if so, you'll need to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

As Jesse Houweling showed, you can use relative paths. However, these are relative to the program's execution folder. You can set that in e.g. the Start Menu, but then the dependency would only have moved from the DNS to the Start Menu.

Therefore I recommend to make the path in the DNS absolute but use Windows variables to set the base part. For exmple use `%CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA%` for the user's app data directory. Google for "windows user directory variable" or go to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for you answer the solution of Jesse Houweling can work, the problem that I'm facing now is that the generated database ".\Database1" is protected an I can't access to it. here the error message : The login failed. Login failed for user 'Acer\Amine'.